# Apple Mach error when running the code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

Hello i'm not so gud in iPhone Development. So i asked you a question it may be simple or not actually i'm getting the project which actually done by some other developer when i trying to run this code it gives me 65 errors which all are almost same it may be due to lack of some frame work or actually i don't know i'm showing you a snapshot of this errors for trying to understand my problem.
Can any body suggest me the solution.

This project having features like Mapkit, iAd i'm familiar with Mapkit but not with iAd ...

Thanks in Advance...

[image]

Comment: The errors are caused by `libGreystripeSDK`. Make sure everything is OK with that: you attached frameworks etc.

Answer (score 1):

These are linker errors.  It looks like the project is being built without being linked to some frameworks you rely on.  Right-click somewhere in your Xcode project (left side), choose Add > Existing Framework... and make sure you have UIKit, Foundation, CoreGraphics, and others you may need, such as MapKit and iAd .